# Implementing a lateral navigation bar in Android

Tags: android, design-patterns

i saw an Android app with a lateral tab that when it was touched it open a navigation bar as you see in the image. How can i do that . is there any librarie to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SlidingMenu, i use it to several apps

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Or you can use the android native component `NavigationDrawer`

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html